# What is the inbound IP for an Event Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I need to configure a on-prem firewall to connect to an Azure Event Hub.

What is the inbound IP for an Event Hub? Is it static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your Event Hub does not get a static inbound IP. It is fronted by a load balancer and you might get different IPs. You can get the IP ranges for all Event Hubs in one Azure region, though: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

In case you only want to send messages using HTTPS, you could build a workaround and front your Event Hub with an Azure Application Gateway which does get a static IP. Might be a bit of an overkill...